# CFB without padding is ignored in Objective-C Security Transforms? : kSecModeCFBKey with kSedPaddingNoneKey seems to use padding anyway

Tags: objective-c, macos, encryption, cryptography, padding

I'm trying to use SecTransformExecute in CFB mode with no padding. I'm trying to get an encrypted result with the same data size as the input (I believe CFB should do this since it just XORs the plaintext against a block generated keystream to create the ciphertext. My test code is below, however, and it seems that using padding options or not results in the same result for a 20 byte string. Curiously, a 32 byte string seems to have 16 bytes of padding added to it by the transforms. Maybe I need to drop down to CommonCrypto for this level of control? What am I missing here? I'd like to create something I can chain new encrypted data onto the end of by passing in the last block as the iv for the next piece. Security Transforms don't seem to have CTR mode available.

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;

// 16 byte buffer with random data for iv
NSData *iv = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:16];
arc4random_buf((void *)[iv bytes], 16);
DDLogVerbose(@"iv: %@, length: %lu", iv, [iv length]);

// something to encrypt
NSString *plainText = @"I'm a secret string."; // 20 bytes
NSData *plainData = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

DDLogVerbose(@"plainText           : %lu : %@", [plainText length], plainText);
DDLogVerbose(@"plainData           : %lu : %@", [plainData length], plainData);

// setup padding encryptor
SecTransformRef encryptPadded = SecEncryptTransformCreate(key, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptPadded, kSecModeCFBKey, NULL, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptPadded, kSecPaddingKey, kSecPaddingPKCS7Key, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptPadded, kSecIVKey, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(iv), &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptPadded, kSecTransformInputAttributeName, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(plainData), &error);

// encrypt with it
NSData *cipherDataPadded = (__bridge NSData *) SecTransformExecute(encryptPadded, &error);
DDLogVerbose(@"cipherDataPadded    : %lu : %@", [cipherDataPadded length], cipherDataPadded);

// setup unpadded encryptor
SecTransformRef encryptUnpadded = SecEncryptTransformCreate(key, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptUnpadded, kSecModeCFBKey, NULL, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptUnpadded, kSecPaddingKey, kSecPaddingNoneKey, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptUnpadded, kSecIVKey, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(iv), &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptUnpadded, kSecTransformInputAttributeName, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(plainData), &error);

// encrypt with it
NSData *cipherDataUnpadded = (__bridge NSData *) SecTransformExecute(encryptUnpadded, &error);
DDLogVerbose(@"cipherDataUnpadded  : %lu : %@", [cipherDataUnpadded length], cipherDataUnpadded);

// something to encrypt
NSString *plainText32 = @"I'm a secret string of 32 bytes."; // 20 bytes
NSData *plainData32 = [plainText32 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

DDLogVerbose(@"plainText32         : %lu : %@", [plainText32 length], plainText32);
DDLogVerbose(@"plainData32         : %lu : %@", [plainData32 length], plainData32);

// setup padded encryptor for 32 bytes
SecTransformRef encryptPadded32 = SecEncryptTransformCreate(key, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptPadded32, kSecModeCFBKey, NULL, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptPadded32, kSecPaddingKey, kSecPaddingPKCS7Key, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptPadded32, kSecIVKey, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(iv), &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptPadded32, kSecTransformInputAttributeName, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(plainData32), &error);

// encrypt with it
NSData *cipherDataPadded32 = (__bridge NSData *) SecTransformExecute(encryptPadded32, &error);
DDLogVerbose(@"cipherDataPadded32  : %lu : %@", [cipherDataPadded32 length], cipherDataPadded32);

// setup unpadded encryptor for 32 bytes
SecTransformRef encryptUnpadded32 = SecEncryptTransformCreate(key, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptUnpadded32, kSecModeCFBKey, NULL, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptUnpadded32, kSecPaddingKey, kSecPaddingNoneKey, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptUnpadded32, kSecIVKey, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(iv), &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(encryptUnpadded32, kSecTransformInputAttributeName, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(plainData32), &error);

// encrypt with it
NSData *cipherDataUnpadded32 = (__bridge NSData *) SecTransformExecute(encryptUnpadded32, &error);
DDLogVerbose(@"cipherDataUnpadded32: %lu : %@", [cipherDataUnpadded32 length], cipherDataUnpadded32);
```

Which produces the following output:

```
>>> plainText           : 20 : I'm a secret string.
>>> plainData           : 20 : <49276d20 61207365 63726574 20737472 696e672e>
>>> cipherDataPadded    : 32 : <54e26843 a6e96b71 6ebe4605 5c10ec1e 28b9c87a a2574f21 66e788c4 dfca3f32>
>>> cipherDataUnpadded  : 32 : <54e26843 a6e96b71 6ebe4605 5c10ec1e 28b9c87a a2574f21 66e788c4 dfca3f32>
>>> plainText32         : 32 : I'm a secret string of 32 bytes.
>>> plainData32         : 32 : <49276d20 61207365 63726574 20737472 696e6720 6f662033 32206279 7465732e>
>>> cipherDataPadded32  : 48 : <54e26843 a6e96b71 6ebe4605 5c10ec1e 63cd5eaf 5e86fb77 d672cd15 528f19b5 2b0bcff4 c5cb2ca6 bc195f9d bba54baf>
>>> cipherDataUnpadded32: 48 : <54e26843 a6e96b71 6ebe4605 5c10ec1e 63cd5eaf 5e86fb77 d672cd15 528f19b5 2b0bcff4 c5cb2ca6 bc195f9d bba54baf>
```

Comment: Hi ijcd and welcome. Have you tried simply cutting down the ciphertext  to the plaintext size? If it won't decrypt, you could try added an X number of bytes to get N times the blocksize again, and use the ciphertext size as the plaintext size. It could be that the implementation simply performs the XOR for the full block.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. If I trim any amount of the cipher text (even 1 byte) the result is the plainText but missing the last 4 bytes. I'm guessing it's decrypting and removing padding, but it's unclear exactly what it's doing.

Comment: @owlstead According the header file and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/System/Reference/SecEncryptTransform_header_reference/Reference/reference.html it "Indicates that PKCS7 padding will be used when encrypting or decrypting."

Comment: @owlstead No... there are two transforms there (comparing the two). The encryptUnpadded transform is using kSecPaddingNoneKey. It's just under // setup unpadded encryptor

Comment: Removed previous comments. I do know that CCCrypt, which is undoubtedly used internally, transforms the texts to 32 bit integers. I think you are running into a bug.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of `SecKey` do you use? For example AES128-CFB needs padding to 16 byte boundaries (cipherDataUnpadded would give `null`).

CFB has only a concept of 'blocks' depending on the used encryption algorithm (AES128 and AES256 are two distinct algorithms).

Also note that PKCS#7 padding adds at least one octet to the length of the message even on lengths that would otherwise meet the block size, see [RFC5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-6.3).